# Laravel @foreach and if statement - How can I display values from two mysql tables that have a common column?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-9

I have a page with 6 categories each one with it's button. Once i press one, it opens a page where items from that category should by filtered by category column. The problem is, either it shows nothing, either it shows everything i have in the table.
E.g. I press the Rims category and on the other page I want to see rims. ("../shop/{category}->Rims")

web.php

```
// shop
Route::get('/shop', function () {
    return view('shop');
})->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('shop');

// categories display
Route::get('/shop', [CategoriesController::class, 'index'])->name('shop.index');


// accessing categories
Route::get('/shop/{name}', [ProductsController::class, 'index'])->name('show-products');
```

ProductsController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\ProfileUpdateRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\View\View;
use App\Models\Categories;
use App\Models\Products;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class ProductsController extends Controller

{
    public function store(Request $product)
    {
        $product->validate([
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:500'],
            'brand' => ['required', 'string', 'max:500'],
            'category' => ['required', 'string', 'max:500'],
            'description' => ['required', 'string', 'max:500'],
            'quantity' => ['required', 'string', 'max:500'],
            'price' => ['required', 'string', 'max:500'],
            'image' => ['required', 'string', 'max:500']
        ]);

        $product = Products::create([
            'name' => $product->name,
            'brand' => $product->brand,
            'category' => $product->category,
            'description' => $product->description,
            'quantity' => $product->quantity,
            'price' => $product->price,
            'image' => $product->image,
        ]);

        return redirect('/shop');
    }

    /**
     * Listeaza categoriile
     */

    public function index(Request $product, $category)
    {
        
            $products = Products::all();
            $categories = Categories::all();

            $category = DB::table('categories')
                ->join('products', 'categories.category', '=', 'products.category')
                ->select('categories.category')
                ->get();
            return view('products', ['category'=>$category, 'products'=>$products]);
    }
}
```

categories table

[image]

products table

[image]

I've tried to make an if statement between ProductController and CategoryController
i.e. $product->category == $category->category

and also to join the categories from both table (see in ProductsController)

Comment: First issue, you're not using the `$product` (which is just a Request object, not a product object/id) or the `$category`. In fact, you're overwriting the `$category` variable inside of your function. I would really suggest using a `category_id` on your products table instead of the category name. If you change a category name, suddenly your product association is broken. You can use that category id to get only products belonging to that category with a `where` clause.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing `Jante` in `products.category`; use the Primary Key of a Category, like `1` for `Jante`, and set up a Relationship between them. Then you'll be able to do `$product->category->category`, which will display `Jante`. Documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: I would also suggest reading up on Eloquent Relationships, specifically the [One to Many](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) (category to products) and [Belongs To](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse) (product to category)

Comment: It would be netter if you posted your table schema as text

Comment: Thank you everybody for helping me out, it worked like a charm :)